# cronjob to remove file where the name contains the date of 7 days ago

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have created a cronjob to backup a database into a sql file with a date in the file name:

```
5 0,10,15,20 * * * /usr/syno/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u<user> -p<password> --opt DATABASE > "/volume5/DATABASE$(date +\%F).sql"`
```

I am trying to have an other cronjob to delete the file of 7 days ago

```
0 0 * * * rm /volume5/DATABASE$(/bin/date -D "%s" -d $(( $(/bin/date +\%s ) - 604800 )) +\%F).sql
```

for example, if the actual date is 2015-08-31, the file of 7 days ago is DATABASE2015-08-24.sql, which should be deleted.

the removal does not work by cron, but does by manual command, so I guess it is only a missing "escape", but I can't figure out where.

Does anybody know where is the problem ?

The "X days ago" option does not work with this date bin.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version? My Ubuntu 11.04 said: `/bin/date: invalid option -- 'D'`

Comment: it is actually on a synology nas, it is a linux based OS.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of trouble by always putting all your command in a script and having cron execute that.

Alternatively, suffer in silence and escape all percent signs WHILE ALSO ensuring that the `\` will be ignored by the shell. In your case, you can do that by adding `\` and removing the quotes:

```
0 0 * * * rm /volume5/DATABASE$(/bin/date -D \%s -d $(( $(/bin/date +\%s ) - 604800 )) +\%F).sql
                                              ^--- Here
```

But again, please don't do that. Make a simple `~/bin/delete_old_backups` script and add that to crontab instead.